# HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, caching

I have an ActionResult which is cached.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "product_Id")]
public ActionResult ProductPreview(Guid product_Id)
{
     // just for testing the cache
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
     return PartialView("ProductPreview", _repository.CreateProductModel(product_Id));
}
```

The good part is that the cache is working. After the first load, the result is shown without any 4seconds delay.

However, i need to clear the cache when some changes has been made to that product.

I tried to clear cache doing like this:

```
public ActionResult RemoveCache()
{
    var url = Url.Action("ProductPreview", "Common");
    // also tried with parameter
    // var url = Url.Action("ProductPreview", "Common", new { @product_Id = "productId" });
    HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I also tried to call RemoveCache method with both ajax and full page refresh, and non of them is working.

What can i do? Where is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `RemoveOutputCacheItem` works only with route parameters, not query string. So you could modify your route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{product_Id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Now you can use the RemoveOutputCacheItem method:

```
public ActionResult RemoveCache(Guid product_Id)
{
    var url = Url.Action("ProductPreview", "Common", new { product_Id = product_Id });
    // the url must look like this: /Common/ProductPreview/eeb2fe32-db58-4fc3-87c8-b47480fbe094
    // for the RemoveOutputCacheItem method to work
    HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Here's my test case:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "product_id")]
    public ActionResult ProductPreview(Guid product_id)
    {
        var model = string.Format(
            "{0} - {1}", 
            product_id, 
            DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
        )
        return PartialView("_Foo", model);
    }

    public ActionResult RemoveCache(Guid product_id)
    {
        var url = Url.Action(
            "ProductPreview", 
            "Home", 
            new { product_id = product_id }
        );
        HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@{
    var productId = Guid.NewGuid();    
}

@Html.ActionLink("product 1", "ProductPreview", new { product_id = Guid.NewGuid() })
<br/>
@Html.ActionLink("product 2", "ProductPreview", new { product_id = productId })
<br/>
@Html.ActionLink("product 3", "ProductPreview", new { product_id = Guid.NewGuid() })
<br />

@Html.ActionLink(
    "clear cache for the second product", 
    "RemoveCache", 
    new { product_id = productId }
)
```

Partial view (`~/Views/Home/_Foo.cshtml`):

```
@model string
@Model
```

and in `global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{product_id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", product_id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

---

UPDATE 2:

Now that you have shown your code it seems that you are using the `Html.RenderAction` helper and the `ProductPreview` is a child action. Child actions are not stored in the same cache as normal views and the `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem` helper doesn't work at all with cached child actions. If you look carefully in my previous example you will see that I used standard links for the `ProductPreview` action.

Currently what you are trying to achieve is not possible in ASP.NET MVC 3. If you want to use donut output caching I would recommend you the [following article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3). Hopefully this functionality will be added in ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: I tried setting route in Global.asax file like this "{controller}/{action}/{product_Id}" and is still not working. I also tried with VaryByCustom="product_Id" and is not working either. Has something to do with the fact that is a ParialView?

Comment: @RaraituL, no, I don't think it's related to the fact that it's a partial view. I have updated my answer to provide my full test case that worked.

Comment: I created a test project with the same scenario, it is not working, i don't understand why. I even removed parameter from ActionResult. Is a web.config setting? do i need to store the cache on server, or change some default setting? I'll post some images

Comment: @RaraituL, ahhhhhhhh, now that you have shown your code it is clear why it doesn't work. You are using Html.RenderAction which means that the ProductPreview is a child action. The HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem method doesn't work at all with child actions. I will update my post.

Comment: Finally, i've been looking also over internet and found about that "ChildActions" cache problem. Now i will play with Donut Caching a little.

Comment: @Darin: 2 years passed and I was just wondering if there is any better solution to remove cached child action results..?