# Remove action from Output Cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

ASP.Net MVC 3.

I found similar questions/answers, but none seem to fix this issue...

Similar: 
[HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968508/httpresponse-removeoutputcacheitem-is-not-working)

[How to "invalidate" portions of ASP.NET MVC output cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288463/how-to-invalidate-portions-of-asp-net-mvc-output-cache)

I am using OutputCache to cache a FileContentResult (an image).

My action looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 300, VaryByParam = "id")]
public FileContentResult Photo(int id) {
    byte[] photo = //GetPhoto;

    return File(photo,"image/jpeg");
}
```

In my view I have to following:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Photo", "Client", new {id = Model.Id})"/>
```

This works fine, and the output caching is working as expected....Now the problem

I am trying to reset the cache after an update.

The code in the action that updates looks like this:

```
var url = Url.Action("Photo", "Client", new {id = Model.Id});
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);
```

The problem is the cache doesn't reset. When I debug, I can't find where the cache object is (I tried System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache, but that doesn't seem to have the cached item).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using this code and it works great!

http://antix.co.uk/Blog/IfModifiedAttribute

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about your case, but I found about child actions on view: they use their own cache (not System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache), which you can access through
static member

```
CacheOutputAttribute.ChildActionCache
```

Cache of child actions has pretty complicated key, which I was not able to calculate.
So, I end up with solution to add a new variable(such a version or timestamp) to my model and pass it as parameter to action method; so I can invalidate my cache with changing this property.

However I'm not 100% sure it is your case, as you are doing no child action caching.