# How to remove output cache for child action (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I try this code

```
public ActionResult RemoveCache(Guid product_Id)  
{  
    var url = Url.Action("ProductPreview", "Common", new { product_Id = product_Id });  
    HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);  
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
```

to remove the output cache for a child action, but it does not work. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1169671/1342180 - specifically the part about setting `[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, ...)[`, on the action methods being cached, of course.

Comment: @AlexSchimp - that works for donut hole caching?

Comment: @AdamTuliper - I probably misunderstood the question.  I thought the OP wanted the action cached initially, and was asking how to clear it later.

Comment: @Alex Schimp - you don't misunderstood the question. My problem is this. But it not work with a child action what called by Html.RenderAction. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968508/httpresponse-removeoutputcacheitem-is-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MVCDonutCaching nuget package at: http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/

See the section entitled "Usage" at:
http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3

for removing items from the cache. There are Html.Action overloads with a param you add to force the donut hole (and thus exclude caching)

```
@Html.Action("Login", "Account", true)
```

The true above means 'don't cache this child action - create a donut hole'

Comment: can you give me a sample for store and remove cache a child action by donut caching? thankyou very much!

Comment: i try use donut caching for child action.
var cacheManager = new OutputCacheManager(); cacheManager.RemoveItem("Home", "List", new { page = 1 });
to remove cache, but it not removed! Please help me!

Comment: it worked very good! thankyou very much! But it not work with a area. Ex: cacheManager.RemoveItem("Home", "List", new { area = "Forum", page = 1 }); NOT WORK! Can you help me? Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 3):

If it is accepted to clear the output cache for ALL chid actions, here is a way:

```
OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache = new MemoryCache("NewRandomStringNameToClearTheCache");
```

`NewRandomStringNameToClearTheCache` should be a random string.

Source References:
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/programmatically-clearing-0