# Using Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem with RedisOutputCacheProvider

Tags: c#, caching, redis, outputcache, stackexchange.redis

I am using the Microsoft [RedisOutputCacheProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider/) and have a very simple PartialView which I am caching based on the current user's *SessionId* via `VaryByCustom`:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "User", Duration = 3600)]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Notifications()
{
    return PartialView("Partials/Notifications");
}
```

This works great and caches as expected, however I wanted to manually expire this OutputCache from another page. I tried:

```
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/Controller/Notifications");
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I also can't see any of the OutputCache keys via either my Redis store, or via my backend code, but I can definitely see the view being cached.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968508/httpresponse-removeoutputcacheitem-is-not-working ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you! That hadn't turned up in my search as I thought it was related to the specific OutputCacheProvider. I'll give this a try tomorrow, not being a ChildOnly action isn't really that important for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you try something like this?

```
//  Get the url for the action method:
var staleItem = Url.Action("Action", "Controller");

//  Remove the item from cache
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(staleItem);
```

I think that you need to hold a reference to your ActionResult.

Best of luck :)

PS: Maybe this link will help you : [The Blog of Dan Esparza](http://www.danesparza.net/2013/01/flushing-the-asp-net-output-cache-using-code/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing custom cache clear logic you may find this useful too:

```
    private void ClearResponseCache(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            return;

        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
        var resolvedAction = urlHelper.Action(
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, 
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
            new RouteValueDictionary(filterContext.ActionParameters));

        if (resolvedAction != null)
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(resolvedAction);
    }
```