# How can I remove output cache for a specific action in a controller without input parameters of action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I have a question about caching in ASP.NET MVC 5.
I have an action that decorates with OutputCacheAttribute.
something like this:
OutputCache(Duration = 900, Location = Server, VaryByParam = "id")

somewhere in my application I want to manage caches and remove them.
I used Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(Url.Action("Index", "Home")) to remove all caches of an action, but it doesn't work.

The **HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem()** method was worked on actions with parameters but I want to clear **all outputcaches** of the action without parameters.

for example:

Controller:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 900, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult About(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Remove by below code:

```
var x = Url.Action("About", "Home");
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(x);
```

Comment: @NitinVarpe that is a useful looking output caching extension, but how does it answer the OP's query about removing output cached for a specified controller?

Comment: There's not enought detail in your post to say, but possibly this answer is useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968508/httpresponse-removeoutputcacheitem-is-not-working

Comment: You are right @MatthewEvans!